# can not select file on ISO-7816-4 smartcard

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu

I am trying to read data from ISO-7816-4 eVCR (electronic vehicle registration card) using 
javax.smartcardio. Whenever I try to select file from card I get SW code 6A86 which 
translates to 'Incorrect P1 or P2 parameter'. I tried many combinations of values for
P1 and P2 and got same result. 
Card itself works fine with other programs and sample code works fine with other cards.
Card I have problem with is same card as in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513383/evrc-smart-cards).

This is code I use:
        Card card = terminal.connect("*");
        System.out.println("ATR: " + Utils.bytes2HexString(card.getATR().getBytes()));

```
    byte aid[] = {(byte)0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x77, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x07, 
        0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xFE, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xAD, (byte) 0xF2};
    ResponseAPDU response = null;
    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
    response = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x0C, aid));
    System.out.println("AID: " + response);

    response = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x02, 0x00, new byte[]{(byte)0xD0, 0x01}));
    System.out.println("SELECT: " + response);
```

And output is:

```
    ATR: 3B:DB:96:00:80:B1:FE:45:1F:83:00:31:C0:64:1A:18:01:00:0F:90:00:52
    AID: ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=9000
    SELECT: ResponseAPDU: 2 bytes, SW=6a86
```

I can't see what am I doing wrong. Do some cards require extra initialization steps or some extra parameters for select?

Comment: Could you try with `0x0C` as P2 (instead of `0x00`)? Maybe the file ID is correct, but it cannot give back any file information (`0x0C` means: don't give me additional info). I'll make this an answer if it works.

Comment: It works with 0x0C. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, posted it as an answer...

Comment: I guess you are using SELECT FILE command where you want the FCP response so you can't use 0C. But my thought is based just on Slovak eVCR communications. I'm using P1=0x02 P2=0x04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `0x0C` as P2 (instead of `0x00`)? Maybe the file ID is correct, but it cannot give back any file information (`0x0C` means: don't give back file information).

It depends on the card operating system and/or application if this would influence the returned status word.